# Is the canvas completely updated on every render loop?

Tags: three.js

Is the canvas updated (I mean redrawn) completely (every vertex, and so every mesh) on every loop of the render function? 
This is a very simple question that helps me clarify how WebGL and Three.js work, and influences my developing strategies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you need to call, either as a display list or explicitly, each vertex for each frame, then the answer is, yes.

The question is slightly misleading because WebGL (based on Open GL) is a state machine that insulates the user (of the API) from the rendering pipeline. So depending on the particular hardware/software implementation that processes your GL calls you don't really know how each vertex or mesh is handled on a frame by frame basis.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a really a simple question and so there really isn't a simple answer

[WebGL is just a rasterization API](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html). Meaning in general you set up a bunch of stuff and it draws pixels. How it draws them and where it draws them is 100% up to you. Whether you clear the canvas or draw a little bit at a time is also up to you.

That said, *most* programs that use WebGL do clear the entire canvas every frame and re-draw every vertex and every pixel.